# How can I read answers to the related questions that appear when I'm drafting a question?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I wanted to ask a question. While I was drafting it, Ask Ubuntu listed some closely related questions that had been answered. I thought those answers might answer the question I was going to ask but being a newbie here I could not see how to read those answers and could not find a tag that my problem relates to. I recently updated from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 if that helps. I ask: how can I read answers to questions? Is there some relevant icon I don't know the meaning of?

Answer (score 9):

While you type in a question, the site suggests other questions that may be similar in a "Similar questions" box. This box shows an excerpt of each question, so you can get an idea whether it could be helpful for your situation or not. The titles of the questions in the box are links. So you can open a question that seems interesting, for example in a new tab, and read the full question and its answers.